# How to just display html video poster for mobile device

Tags: html, css, video, mobile, poster

I currently have a HTML video within a div that auto plays for desktop browsers. I'm trying to implement a fix that DISABLES the `video` for mobile and only displays the video POSTER in its place. I feel like it should be a simple fix, but I can't find any CSS or JS to do this.

Code below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 no-padding">
         <video loop muted autoplay poster="images/joe-rule/banner.jpg" class="width">
            <source src="images/joe-rule/video-reel.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
    </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is what I did

in html:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-1 no-padding">
     <video loop muted autoplay class="width">
        <source src="images/joe-rule/video-reel.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
</video>
</div>
```

in js:

check if the page is loaded in mobile

`if (isMobile) {
      $(".col-1 no-padding").find('video').attr('poster', 'images/joe-rule/banner.jpg');
}`

So that the poster will only be displayed in mobile.

you may need to search the use of "isMobile" or any other to check if the page is loaded in mobile.

Comment: $(".col-1 no-padding") should be $(".col-1.no-padding")